# Camel split xlsx stream

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, apache-camel

do you think it is possible to split the stream of an xlsx via camel?
For example to split a csv I do this

```
.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
```

or for a xml

```
.split(body().tokenizePair("startToken", "endToken", true))
        .streaming()
```

Comment: Isn't an XLSX file just an XML that is zipped?

Comment: Don't see XLSX in the list of supported formats: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/